# What is wrong with this javascript (try to do a time edit)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a edit for time entry. The user must enter time in quarter increments, for example they must enter 2 or 2.50 or 5.75 but not 1.56. I cannot see what is wrong with this code:

```
    var time:Double = 2.00;
    var hour:Double = Math.floor(time);
    var dif:Double = (time - hour).toFixed(2);

    if (dif==0 || dif==.25 || dif==.50 || dif==.75)
    {true}
    {false}
```

Comment: Floating point precision is not your friend in this case.

Comment: You could probably use an 'else' after {true}

Comment: `console.log(dif)` will tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: also some syntax issue too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: The else was the problem. Thanks.